Custom fonts with javascript do not work in A-frame and Vue
If in App.vue I write it, works:
<a-entity
          geometry="primitive: plane; width: 4; height: 0"
          material="visible: false"          
          text="value: Extraño; color: blue; font: custom-msdf.json; font-image: custom-msdf.png; negate: false"
          position="0 2 -2"></a-entity>

The letter ñ in the word "Extraño" is seen.
But if I create the entity in javascript, no:
const titleEntity = document.createElement('a-entity');
titleEntity.setAttribute('class', 'title');
titleEntity.setAttribute('geometry', 'primitive: plane; height: 0.02; width: 0.23');
titleEntity.setAttribute('material', 'visible:false');
titleEntity.setAttribute('position', '0 0.01 0.076');
titleEntity.setAttribute('rotation', '0 0 90');
titleEntity.setAttribute('negate', 'false');
titleEntity.setAttribute('text', `value:Extraño; font: custom-msdf.json; font-image: custom-msdf.png; negate: false`);

If I use:
titleEntity.setAttribute('text', `value:English;`);

Then, I can't use Non-ASCII Characters
